# LinqToTwitter doesn't work in PCL in Xamarin.Forms for UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms, linq-to-twitter

I know that LinqToTwitter supports UWP and it support Xamarin.Forms, but using the UniversalAuthoriser (which supports UWP) namespace is not available when called from within the PCL in my Xamarin.Forms project. It works if I place the code in the UWP project though, but then I don't have a way of referencing that from the PCL. Any help would be appreciated.
I am using Linq2Twitter v4.x

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that L2T supports the PCL profile used by Xamarin Forms.

However, anytime you have a library that works in your platform project but does not work in a PCL project, you can expose that behavior in your PCL via [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/).

You could also try building the source for L2T in a PCL project that uses the Xamarin Forms profile.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, I will look into the DependencyService you suggested but just a small clarification. L2T works in a Xamarin.Forms PCL when targetting iOS, Android, and WP8.1 but it doesn't support a specific namespace that I need to use for targeting UWP.

Comment: Hi Jason, I used DependencyService like you suggested and it works great. Thanks for introducing me to this useful feature.

Comment: Glad it worked.  Please upvote and accept the answer if it was helpful